# 2 coins 1 flip - probability of a trick coin producing tails (given that the trick coin is double-sided tails)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

You have two coins in your hand. Out of the two coins, one is a real coin (heads and tails) and the other is a trick coin with tails on both sides.

You are blindfolded and forced to choose a random coin and then toss it in the air. The coin lands with tails facing upwards.

Find the probability that this is the trick coin (faulty | tails)

Is the answer 0.33 or 0.66?

Comment: To emphasize, $0.33$ is not the same thing as $\frac{1}{3}$.  If you mean to say $\frac{1}{3}$ then *say that rather than some unequal number*.  Same for $0.66$... Mathematics requires precise language and being lazy about things like this will cause errors in the future.

Comment: Now... why did you ask "*Is the answer 0.33 or 0.66?*"  Did you have some way of thinking it was one of these?  What reasoning did you use to arrive at these possibilities and why has your reasoning not led you far enough to have picked only one of those as possibilities?  What about the other possibility makes it sound plausible?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was misinterpreting () thinking it was $\frac{1}{2}$ instead of 1 - i.e. what is the probability of getting a trick coin $\frac{1}{2}$ rather than the probability of having a trick coin when you're certain it's faulty (1). It lead my calculation to be $\frac{1}{3}$ instead of $\frac{2}{3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Bayes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).

Let

$$\begin{align}
A &:= \text{The flipped coin is the faulty one} \\
B &:= \text{The result is tails}
\end{align}$$

Then

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)} = \frac{1 \cdot \frac{1}{2}}{\frac{3}{4}^{(*)}} = \frac{\frac{2}{4}}{\frac{3}{4}} = \frac{2}{3}$$

$(*)\quad  P(B) $ is $\frac{3}{4}$, because overall there are $3$ tails out of $4$ faces.

So the answer is $\frac{2}{3} = 0.66...$

Answer (score 2):

Alternative (which is more direct):

There are $3$ equiprobable coin faces that show a tail.

Exactly $2$ of them are part of the coin that has $2$ tails.

So the probability that the coin has indeed $2$ tails is $\frac23$.